# Characters not allowed with powershell in the Cireson smlets Get-SCSMEnumeration

Tags: powershell, servicemanager

I am trying to import a enum list into this Service Manager Cireson Asset tool.

```
Import-Module smlets
$mpName = "CompanyName.ListValues.HWA.CatalogModels"
$enum = Get-SCSMEnumeration -Name Cireson.AssetManagement.CatalogItemModelEnum$
$types = Import-Csv -Path "E:\AssetFiles\Models.csv"

$mp = New-SCSMManagementPack -ManagementPackName $mpName -FriendlyName $mpName -DisplayName $mpName -PassThru

foreach ($t in $types) {

    #Add-SCSMEnumeration -Parent $enum -Name ($enum.Name + "." + $t.Model.Replace(' ','')) -DisplayName $t.Model -Ordinal 10 -ManagementPack $mp

    Add-SCSMEnumeration -Parent $enum -Name ($enum.Name + "." + $t.Model.Replace(' ','')) -DisplayName $t.Model -ManagementPack $mp

}
```

1. Seems that Ordinal: is prompted when I do not include it, must be built into the SCSM import module ?
2. It seems to skip some records that are the same, why?
3. Doesn't like certain characters?

> The 'ID' attribute is invalid - The value
>   'Cireson.AssetManagement.CatalogItemModelEnum.Intel(R)Xeon(R)CPUE5640@2.67GHz'
>   is invalid according to its  datatype 'ManagementPackUniqueIdentifier'
>   - The Pattern constraint failed. ---> System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaException: The Pattern constraint failed.

data in the csv file looks like the following:  "Model" is the column header

```
Model
HP DL320p Gen 8 
ProLiant BL460c G7
ProLiant BL460c G1
ProLiant BL460c G1
ProLiant BL460c G1
ProLiant BL460c Gen8
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5640 @ 2.67GHz 
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5670 @ 2.93GHz
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the processor speed stuff from the type: `$t.Model.Replace(' ','') -replace('@.*', '')`

Comment: Don't I want to not worry about the contents of the csv file though?  Just make sure powershell ignores any special character in the reading of any CSV  ?